# При открытии сформированного бандла возникает ошибка "Cannot read property 'locals' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

**[Ссылка на репозиторий](https://github.com/corocoto/cars-magazine.git), в котором хранится исходный код.**

### Последовательность действий для воспроизведения ошибки:

1. Скачать исходники;
2. Установить зависимости;
3. Запустить один из доступных скриптов в `package.json`;
4. Дождаться сборки;
5. 

- Если запущен `dev` - дождаться момента, когда `webpack-dev-server` отобразит результат сборки в браузере;
- Если запущен `build` - самостоятельно открыть `index.html` в директории `dist`;

6. Открыть консоль браузера.

> P.S. Должна появиться следующая ошибка:
> [image: ошибка после сборки проекта]

Comment: Подебагайте мой код за меня?))) проблема в том что код обращается к `undefined` как к объекту, пытаясь получить значения по ключу `locals`. Покликайте на ссылки с картинки поищите место такого вызова. Если из бандла не понять конкретное место, попробуйте использовать SourceMap.

Comment: @mego4iter, нет. продебажить могу сам. просто провозился некоторое время, так и не смог найти ошибку. подумал, может быть с этим уже кто-то сталкивался

Comment: На сколько могу судить по строке с `...style.css` кажется что интерпритатор спатыкается имено при выполнении стилей. Поищите где в стилях используете что то похожее на `locals`

Comment: у вас в коде `require('styles.css')`, это очевидно. Вы прописали стили в скрипты. Вот он и пытается воспроизвести файл css в `eval()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В разделе `rules` для css стилей необходимо прописать следующее:

```js
{
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader',
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                postcssOptions: {
                    config: path.resolve(paths.root, 'postcss.config.js')
                },
                sourceMap: true,
             },
        },
    ]
}
```